# Can the SPFileCollection.Add method check if I file has changed?

Tags: 2013, powershell, file-upload, script, cmdlets

I'm using the sharepoint powershell cmdlets to upload files to a document library like so:

```
# Set the variables 
$WebURL = “http://portal.contoso.com/sites/stuff” 
$DocLibName = “Docs” 
$FilePath = “C:\Docs\stuff\Secret Sauce.docx” 


# Get a variable that points to the folder 
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL 
$List = $Web.GetFolder($DocLibName) 
$Files = $List.Files 

# Get just the name of the file from the whole path 
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("\")+1) 

# Load the file into a variable 
$File= Get-ChildItem $FilePath

# Upload it to SharePoint 
$Files.Add($DocLibName +"/" + $FileName,$File.OpenRead(),$false) 
$web.Dispose()
```

Does [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection.add.aspx) (maybe another class) have a mechanism to check if the file being added is newer than a file of the same name already in the collection? It looks like the method can only overwrite or not overwrite a file of the same name.

Before handling this myself (just comparing modified dates of files being added) I want to be sure there isn't something in the sharepoint API that already takes care of this.